# How to check if string within object is unique in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, comparison, lodash

I have an *array* of *strings*:

```
var arr = [
    {str: 'abc'},
    {str: 'def'},
    {str: 'abc'},
    {str: 'ghi'},
    {str: 'abc'},
    {str: 'def'},
];
```

I am searching for a **smart way** to add a boolean attribute `unique` to the *objects* whether `str` is unique:

```
var arr = [
    {str: 'abc', unique: false},
    {str: 'def', unique: false},
    {str: 'abc', unique: false},
    {str: 'ghi', unique: true},
    {str: 'abc', unique: false},
    {str: 'def', unique: false},
];
```

My solution contains three `_.each()` loops and it looks terrible... Solutions with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) preferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `where` to filter an object. Then you can know if your string is unique in the object.

```
_.each(arr, function(value, key) {
    arr[key] = {
        str : value.str,
        unique : _.where(arr, { str : value.str }).length == 1 ? true : false
    };
});
```

Maybe better version with a `map` :

```
arr = _.map(arr, function(value) {
    return {
        str : value.str,
        unique : _.where(arr, { str : value.str }).length == 1 ? true : false
    };
});
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. gonna have a nicer weekend now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any libraries, vanilla js works:

```js
var map = [];
var arr = [
    {str: 'abc'},
    {str: 'def'},
    {str: 'abc'},
    {str: 'ghi'},
    {str: 'abc'},
    {str: 'def'},
];
  
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (map.indexOf(obj.str) < 0) {
      map.push(obj.str);
      obj.unique = true;
      return;
    }
    arr.forEach(function(o) {
      if (o.str === obj.str) o.unique = false;
    });
});

document.write("<pre>");  
document.write(JSON.stringify(arr, null, "  "));
document.write("</pre>");
```